# How to fetch the values of a dynamic select list in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson, selectlist

I'm trying to get the values of my dynamically filled select list in a global variable. This is how I get and fill the select list:

My dropdown.js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#slctTable").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_fields.php?table=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
            var options = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }
        $("#slctField").html("");
        $("#slctField").append(options);
        $("#slctField").change();
    });    
    });
});
```

So after this I tryed this code in my main.js scgript to get the values of the select lists:

```
$('#slctField > option').each(function(){
    console.log(this.value); // Use this.value to get the value of the option
});

var options = [];
$('#slctField > option').each(function(){
    options.push(this.value);
});

console.log(options);
```

But when I run my scripts this the result I get back:
[image]

But when I copy and paste the code in firebug and run it. I get the result i want.So I think the select lists aren't filled yet when i try to get the values. But I'm stuck on this for a long time and I don't know what to do at the moment.

Comment: You're very correct! Your GET is asynchronous and will likely complete long after your main.js code has finished executing. You'll want to make sure your modifications to the global variable is tied to your callbacks in some way so its guaranteed to run afterwards.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought. But how can i tie the callback to a global variable?

Comment: I posted an answer with 2 examples.

Answer (score 0):

Because [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchronous, to solve your problem you can trigger a [custom event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) when the select is completed (at the end of getJSON success).

In my example I used this slctFieldFilled new event.

This is a different approach. Another possible solution can be based on callbacks: at the end of an asynchronous function execute the callback function, like the getJSON does.

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users', success = function (data) {
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].id + "</option>";
    }
    $("#slctTable").append(options);
    $("#slctTable").change();
  });
  
  $("#slctTable").on('change', function(e) {
    var par1 =  $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users", success = function(data) {
      var options = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].id + "</option>";
      }
      $("#slctField").html("");
      $("#slctField").append(options);
      $("#slctField").change();
      
      //
      // Now, the slctField is filled, so trigger your custom event
      //
      $('#slctField').trigger('slctFieldFilled', options);
    });
  });
  
  $("#slctField").change(function() {
    var par1 = $(slctTable).val();
    var par2 = $(slctField).val();
    $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users", success = function(data) {
      var options = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].id + "</option>";
      }
      $("#slctAttribute").html("");
      $("#slctAttribute").append(options);
      $("#slctAttribute").change();
    });
  });

  
  // listen on custom event...
  $('#slctField').on('slctFieldFilled', function(e, optionVariable) {
      var options = [];
       $(optionVariable).each(function(index, element){
            options.push(this.value);
       });
       $('#log').text(options);
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<select id="slctTable"></select>
<select id="slctField"></select>
<select id="slctAttribute"></select>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: Thank for all the help! This was what i was looking for! Both you'r answer aswell as Austin Schmidt answer worked.

Comment: The only thing is, how do i make `var options` a global variable now? because it's in the function?

Comment: @L.Grunn If you neglect the var and put options = []; instead of var options = []; it will become a global automatically. You could also reference it as window.options = []; and window.options.push(...);

Comment: @L.Grunn You may always pass the local variable options as an argument to the event and so you may use it like you want. Snippet updated

Comment: @L.Grunn Please, take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming.

Answer (score 0):

You're very correct! Your GET is asynchronous and will likely complete long after your main.js code has finished executing. You'll want to make sure your modifications to the global variable is tied to your callbacks in some way so its guaranteed to run afterwards.

```
var options = [];
$("#slctField").change(function()
{
    $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_attributes.php?table=" + $(slctTable).val() ,"field=" + $(slctField).val() , success = function(data)
    {
        ...
        //Option 1: Append the values inside your callback. 
        //Use window.options because you have another local variable options(window.XX calls any global XX)
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            ...
            window.options.push(data[i]);
        }
        //Option 2: Basically the same thing as 1, call a function that does the same thing at the end of your callback
        populateOptions();
    });    
});
function populateOptions(){
    $('#slctField > option').each(function(){
        options.push(this.value);
    });
}
```

There's plenty of other ways to do it as well as long as you guarantee it executes after your GET. If you have any questions, post a comment. Be careful about the scope of options since you have multiple variables named options(or consider different names so that you can't be confused later on!).

Comment: Thanks, that was what i was looking for! Finally! Only i tried you'r first option and that gave me an error `ReferenceError: options is not defined`. But second one worked.

Comment: You have to declare the global variable options before the first option will work.

Comment: If I do that i get `TypeError: window.optionsFields.push is not a function`.

Comment: It sounds like you have another global `optionFields`. You should define it(as an array) before the function is called.

Comment: Is your new code working or are you still getting an error?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix that @Austin?

Comment: It looks fine on mine, can you post your full code somewhere, including the JSON response?